# Is it ever possible to call pointInside: on an irregular shape?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c++, openframeworks

I'm drawing an oblong 'egg' shape (on iOS), and want to use it as a boundary for particles. My thought is to use the curve paths to make a `UIView` and then use `hitTest:withEvent:` or `pointInside:withEvent:` to enforce boundary collision.

The problem is, of course, that `UIView` is always rectangular. How would you go about checking to see if a point is inside an irregular shape like this?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
int w = rect.size.width;
int h = rect.size.height;
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, w/2, h/5);
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, w*0.1, h/4.3, w*0.1, h*0.82, w/2, h*0.8);
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, w*0.9, h*0.82, w*0.9, h/4.3, w/2, h*0.2);
```

I'm using **openFrameworks**, for what that's worth. This code is just Obj-C but I'm open to any C++/obj-C++ solutions out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a `CGPathRef` you can use `CGPathContainsPoint`. You can use that same `CGPathRef` to render into the context. You could also call `CGContextPathContainsPoint` on the context containing the path, but depending on when you need to test you might not have a context.  And another alternative is the `containsPoint` selector on `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: Is this possible on the iOS? My `CGPath`s aren't being drawn as my `CGContextMoveToPoint` (etc)'s were. `UIBezierPath` would be super but that's not on iOS either. (Sorry, updating original question to specify iOS now)

Comment: CGPathContainsPoint is in iOS 2.0 and later, and UIBezierPath is in iOS 3.2 and later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code this from scratch, http://www.softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0103/algorithm_0103.htm goes through a couple of different algorithms that will work for an arbitrary polygon.

Comment: That's a great overview of the underlying mechanism. Thanks!